# Laravel With Wherehas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using a query to get the companies that belong to a city, that belongs to an event.

```
$companies = Event::find($id)->city->companies;
```

Now in my view i'm iterating through the companies to output the persons that work there as following

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
    @foreach($company->persons as $person)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The only problem is it's also showing me **companies that don't have persons**

### So any idea how i can modify my query to show only the companies that have persons

I was thinking about WhereHas, but I can't seem to wrap myself around the logic of combining the two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work but you can try with this:

```
$companies = Event::find($id)->city->companies()->has('persons')->get();
```

Comment: it is working! Didn't know about the "has" function! thank you!

Comment: @Notflip You can look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations for details and more complex relation queries

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations):

> [...] you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a
>   relationship [...] To do so, you may use the has method.

Something like this might work:

```
Event::find($id)->city()->companies()->has('persons')->get();
```

Given that I don't know the exact return objects for proper method chaining.